# What low level language does apple silicon support?

Tags: arm, apple-silicon

Apple's ARM-based processor seems promising and more battery efficient than intel. What I like to know is that what low level language does it support? As for intel x86, it is primarily written in C/C++. Even though apple silicon has rosetta2 to compile third party libraries, will it still natively support low-level languages like x86_64(c/c++).

Comment: From the invention of C to the present the whole idea is to abstract the underlying architecture.  There are C and C++ compilers for ARM just like x86.  A very large percentage of the code will just recompile and be done with it.  Operating systems abstract the underlying drivers and the drivers at time abstract the underlying architecture, so here again it is mostly just a re-compile.  Just like the powerpc to x86 transition the x86 to arm transition should be smooth.

Comment: So, basically arm and intel underline architecture work much the same way but different performance. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Nope, has nothing to do with that, underlying architecture has nothing to do with high level code and compilers.  Underlying architecture is like alphabets and languages.  Because a math textbook is written in lets say English, does that mean it is not possible to translate that book to german?  No that makes no sense.   Less so than that example because you dont have to change the code well over 99% plus many nines after the decimal point.  From a percentage perspective none of the code has to change.

Comment: You simply recompile it, not sure where the confusion is.  C was created in the 1960s, hand in hand with unix, to avoid the problem they were having with different architectures on the darpanet.  Allowing for the operating system to be written in a non-target specific language then you compile to the target.  printf("Hello World\n"); wasnt invented on x86, x86 was decades later, x86, mips, arm, powerpc, avr, risc-v, pdp11, pdp8, 6502, etc, etc, etc.  All have compilers that will compile that code, to something that will run, without a single change to the source code.

Comment: Are you confused about programming languages and compilers?  Not sure what your real question is at this point.  C has nothing to do with x86.

Comment: Got it. Thank you for your explanation,

Comment: silicone is the material that prostheses and facial filler are made of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we are under NDA for deeperr details, but from Apple docs, You will be allowed to make projects in Xcode using:

C
C++
Swift
ObjC
in ANY combinations

there are some limitations in using ASM, as per Apple docs.